# What is the difference between ^ and \A , $ and \Z in regex?

Tags: regex

In regular expressions:

- What is the difference between `^` and `\A`?
- What is the difference between `$` and `\Z`?

Comment: Which language's flavor of regex?

Comment: In PHP. PHP since 5.3 uses only PCRE (Perl compatible Reg Ex) and other ENgines have been deprecated in PCRE's favor. So , basically PERL style

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020792/regular-expressions-difference-between-and-a

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In single-line mode, `$` matches either the end of the string, or just before the newline at the end of the string. In multiline mode `$` matches before each newline in the string. `\Z` always matches only the end of the string regardless of the line mode. Same with `^` versus `\A`.

Comment: sorry but that is not quite right.  `\Z` matches the end of the string **OR** one before the end of the string if the last char is a `\n`.  For the absolutely, non-oh-just-in-case version, you want `\z` (little zed not BIG ZED), which is guaranteed to match only if there are no chars left. In some regex languages, BTW, what counts as a newline may be flexible; if you’re lucky it will match `(?:(?>\r\n)|\v)` for any linebreak sequence, where `\v` is the Unicode `\p{Vertical_Space}` property.

Comment: One other thing: single-line mode is *not* the opposite of multiline mode; they're completely separate.  Multiline mode alters the behavior of `^` and `$` as you described, while single-line mode allows `.` to match line-separator characters.

Comment: And a note to the tchrist's comment: in Python `re`, `\Z` is equal to `\z` in Perl/.NET/Java/PCRE.

Answer (score 9):

See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions).

> The \A  and \Z  are just like "^" and
>   "$", except that they won't match
>   multiple times when the /m modifier is
>   used, while "^" and "$" will match at
>   every internal line boundary. To match
>   the actual end of the string and not
>   ignore an optional trailing newline,
>   use \z .

Answer (score 4):

They are different when it comes to matching string with multiple lines.

^ can match at the start of the string **and** after each line break. \A only ever matches at the start of the string

$ can match at the end of the string **and** before each line break.  \Z only ever matches at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

An additional example in Python because the above ones are a bit loaded. In Python when using MULTILINE mode ^ and $ will also match before each linebreak, whilst when using /A and /Z it will only match begin/end of the string, respectively.

```
import re

string = "Test test test xzz\nTest 123 Test xzz"
#Test test test xzz
#Test 123 Test xzz

#Multiline mode
re.findall(r'xzz$', string, re.MULTILINE)
#['xzz', 'xzz']

re.findall(r'xzz\Z', string, re.MULTILINE)
#['xzz']

#No multiline mode
re.findall(r'xzz$', string)
#['xzz']

re.findall(r'xzz\Z', string)
#['xzz']
```

Answer (score 0):

They are different indeed.

```
import re

#A. Match only single line examples
print(re.findall('^B.+d$', 'Beginning to end'))
#['Beginning to end'

print(re.findall('\AB.+d$', 'Beginning to end'))
#['Beginning to end']


#B. Match multiple lines but MULTILINE option not enabled examples
print(re.findall('^B.+d$', 'Beginning to end\nBusy street end\nBeer nuts and almond'))
#

print(re.findall('\AB.+d$', 'Beginning to end\nBusy street end\nBeer nuts and almond'))
#

#C. Match multiple lines with MULTILINE option enabled (^ and \A with re.M) examples
print(re.findall('^B.+d$', 'Beginning to end\nBusy street end\nBeer nuts and almond', re.M))
#['Beginning to end', 'Busy street end', 'Beer nuts and almond']

print(re.findall('\AB.+d$', 'Beginning to end\nBusy street end\nBeer nuts and almond', re.M))
#['Beginning to end']


#D. \Z with ^ and \A with re.M examples
print(re.findall('^B.+d\Z', 'Beginning to end\nBusy street end\nBeer nuts and almond', re.M))
#['Beer nuts and almond']

print(re.findall('\AB.+d\Z', 'Start to finish\nSpecial fish\nSuper fresh', re.M))
#
```