# Regular expression to to match alphanumeric followed by underscore and later alphanumeric

Tags: regex

I am not so great at regular expressions so I would like to understand if the regular expression which I have made is ok or it can be improved.

Regular expression conditions:

1. Maximum 20 characters allowed.
2. First 3 - 4 characters should be alphanumeric. It can either be 3 or 4 characters.
3. The next character should be a underscore(_) only.
4. Followed by that there can be another 1-15 alphanumeric characters.

I have made a regular expression like this :

```
^[[:alnum:]]{3,4}(_)[[:alnum:]]{1,15}$
```

Is this a good practice or can I improve further?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please comment and let me know after down voting. As I am learning I really do not know the reason behind down vote. Thanks

Comment: I upvoted your question to counter the previous downvote. I don't see why anyone would downvote this question and not give a reason. Perhaps it was for adding the ruby tag (since there's nothing about ruby in the question)?

Comment: @BreandánDalton Thanks removed it. Instead of ^ and $ can I use \A and \z respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression correctly fulfills the conditions you specify. In addition, it also captures the underscore, which you don't need to do. So you could simply write

```
^[[:alnum:]]{3,4}_[[:alnum:]]{1,15}$
```

Also, as you are aware, this expression matches the entire line, not just a portion of a line, so whitespace at either end of the string could cause you problems if the line could contain it (cf UNIX/Windows different line endings).

[What is the difference between ^ and \A , $ and \Z in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250062/what-is-the-difference-between-and-a-and-z-in-regex) shows the difference between \A \z and ^ $ (including an interesting comment about \z and trailing newline)